# Rspec test help - email uniqueness test failing yet it works in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have been creating an application based on the Hartl course, and have added in the concept of Organization, which has_many users. The tests are all the standard tests Hartl recommends up to section 9.2 of the guide book. Since implementing Organizations into the application, one of the test cases is failing "when email address is already taken" - this should block a user from signing up with the same email address twice. What is odd is the fact that this is working in the application itself (form error - "users email address is already taken" thrown) but not in my tests. Can you help and indicate why this has broken please?

User code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :organization
#accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(?:\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
validates :organization, presence: true
```

Organization code:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :organization_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }, uniqueness: true 
has_many :users, :inverse_of => :organization
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
```

User spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
 before do 
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end

 subject { @user }

 it { should respond_to(:name) }
 it { should respond_to(:email) }
 it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
 it { should respond_to(:password) }
 it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
 it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
 it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
 it { should be_valid }
...
describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
        user_with_same_email = @user.dup
        user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
        user_with_same_email.save
    end

it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

Factory Girl Code:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :organization do
    organization_name       "Example Org"

    trait :wrong do
        organization_name   "Wrong Org"
    end

    trait :also_wrong do
        organization_name   "Another Wrong Org"
    end
end

factory :user do
    association :organization
    name                    "Example Name"
    email                   "email@example.com"
    password                "foobar"
    password_confirmation   "foobar"

    trait :wrong_org do
        association :organization, :factory => [:organization, :wrong]
    end

    trait :wrong_org2 do
        association :organization, :factory => [:organization, :also_wrong]
    end
end
end
```

The error thrown from the Rails console is as follows:

> 1) User when email address is already taken should not be valid
>        Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
>          expected `#<User id: 5287, name: "Example Name", email: "email@example.com", created_at: "2014-07-22 15:04:33", updated_at: "2014-07-22 15:04:33", password_digest: "$2a$04$jrxyuz9e574BoaAhZm6xkOUeAY5spyDut2CCEvAykMu...", organization_id: 5025, remember_token: "339dfafcac7bc5925dbf4e44f60a782f3bbbaa1b">.valid?` to return false, got true

I've tried changing the code inside the test, but no matter what I do it keeps throwing an error. As mentioned above, when I open up the application in my local server I can use all functions, and when I try to sign up using a duplicate email address it won't let me. What's wrong with my test code?

Comment: `@user` is still valid, and always will be. It is `user_with_same_email` that is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@user` is completely valid:

- You create your subject, `@user`. This is valid
- You create the `user_with_same_email`
- *That* user is not valid, because it has the same email as `@user`
- Saving `user_with_same_email` returns false, but that is not checked in your test
- The duplicate user is not saved in the db
- The original user is still valid

A correct test would just `#dup`the user (or make a new one with the same email), and then check that the *new* record is not valid.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried building a new user (even making a new factory that creates a new user with the same email) and the error still gets thrown. Also, this test hasn't been changed since adding in the Organizations feature, and was passing beforehand. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong.

Comment: Actually, I did fix it with your answer in the end. Thanks for getting me on the right track. I created a new user with the same email address (not using FactoryGirl because ActiveRecord didn't like that approach) and it solved this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well if you create a new record with FactoryGirl, it will raise an exception on failure. You can _build_ it with FG though, and then run your test on it.